# How to include or exclude a specific dependency in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am building a springboot app with gradle which needs to connect a DB. For my local dev i want to have H2 DB but when I deploy in my actual env I want to psotgresql so I need to exclude H2 DB when I package and run my app dev/test/prod environments.

Not able to achieve this. Either both dependencies are getting inlcuded or excluded.

```groovy
dependencies {
    //other dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    //nonLocalImplementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    //implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'

    if (project.hasProperty("local")) {
        implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    }

    if(project.hasProperty("test") || project.hasProperty("prod")){
        implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    }
}

bootRun {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', project.findProperty("activeProfile") ?: 'default'
}
```

```sh
./gradlew bootRun -PactiveProfile=local
```

gives me compile time error bcos my code will expect a H2 webserver class to be available

Comment: [Configuring Gradle and Spring Boot with H2 for local development](https://dev.to/baso53/configuring-gradle-and-spring-boot-with-h2-for-local-development-8fp)

Comment: Ditch that complexitity and just add `developmentOnly com.h2database:h2` which will only include it at development time and will leave it out of the generated artifact.

Comment: @M.Deinum Its working but just want to understand which will only include it at development time? Meaning when we package this a jar or docker image it wont include h2 DB dependency?If so how will it excluding?

Comment: As stated it is only for development, the spring boot plugin willl automatically exclude the `developmentOnly` when building an artificat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot already provides a special scope for this [`developmentOnly`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.configuring.including-development-only-dependencies). This is a special scope for dependencies that are needed during development but shouldn't be in the build artifact.

The scope is also documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.configuring.including-development-only-dependencies) in the Spring Boot Gradle plugin documentation.

So instead of the complexity with the different properties and have separated builds for various environments just use the specific scope.

```
dependencies {
    //other dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    //nonLocalImplementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    //implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'

    developmentOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
}
```

With the dependencies above H2 will be used locally during development but not included in the artifact. The embedded database for H2 takes precedence over the PostgreSQL driver (due to embedded) and hence it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, this making this more complex you can try like this to make conditional dependencies -

```
configurations {
    localOnly
    postgresOnly
}

dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'

    localOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    postgresOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    if (project.hasProperty("local")) {
        implementation project.configurations.localOnly
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("test") || project.hasProperty("prod")) {
        implementation project.configurations.postgresOnly
    }
}

bootRun {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', project.findProperty("activeProfile") ?: 'default'
}
```

Let me know if you're still facing issue.

Comment: The Spring Boot and dependency management plugin already provides the `developmentOnly`configuration for this.

Comment: Above said configuration is not working. Getting error Adding a Configuration as a dependency is no longer allowed as of Gradle 8.0